# VBA - How to sort values in listbox in ascending order?

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to sort items in my userform listbox. So far I have the code below:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Temp As Variant
With ListBoxName
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 2
        For j = i + 1 To .ListCount - 1
            If .List(i) > .List(j) Then
                Temp = .List(j)
                .List(j) = .List(i)
                .List(i) = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With
```

This code works but sadly, it does not sort the numbers properly. I want to sort the numbers the following way:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14

but my code sorts these number like this:
1,10,11,12,13,14,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

How can I sort items in listbox numerically in ascending order? I populate the listbox using `ListBoxName.AddItem` command. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are they always numbers? if so, `Dim Temp as Long`

Comment: Try replacing of `If .List(i) > .List(j) Then` with `If CLng(.List(i)) > CLng(.List(j)) Then` and `Temp = CLng(.List(j))` But if you have also strings in the list box, the code will return an error...

Comment: Thank you for your help. Scott's solution did not work (I don't know why). FaneDuru's idea worked exactly as I needed, I can easily sort my listbox now. It consists of only numbers, so there is no issue with potential error caused by strings. Thanks to you both for your help with my issue.

Comment: Only declaring `Temp as Long` did not help because the comparison is done before allocating the compared value to `Temp` variable, no matter what type it is... I will transform my comment in an answer, then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, please replacing of

```
If .List(i) > .List(j) Then
```

with

```
If CLng(.List(i)) > CLng(.List(j)) Then
```

and change:

```
Temp = CLng(.List(j))
```

In this way, the comparison it is done between numbers, not between strings.

But if you have also strings in the list box, the code will return an error...

Answer (score 2):

If you need to sort a listbox with multiple columns:

```
Sub SortListbox(LBX As msforms.ListBox, Col As Integer)
DisableEventiUF = True
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Temp As Variant
Dim Y  As Integer
With LBX
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 2
        For j = i + 1 To .ListCount - 1
            If .List(i, Col) >= .List(j, Col) Then
                For Y = 0 To .ColumnCount - 1
                Temp = .List(j, Y)
                .List(j, Y) = .List(i, Y)
                .List(i, Y) = Temp
                Next Y
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With
DisableEventiUF = False
End Sub
```